Possibly 30 year old film where people who have died go to an island
I'm trying to find a film I saw over 30 years ago. It's not a horror. All I remember is people who have died being taken by boat to an island, with a massive hotel like building. Here they stay all the while they're remembered by the living. Much more than that I don't remember, except there were exceptions to Very famous people being allowed to stay there forever,though the reason was never explained. I'd love to see it again but have spent hours trying to find it to no avail.

Well, if people stay there as long as they're remembered by the living, then logically famous historical figures would stay indefinitely, until they're forgotten, right?  Unfortunately I don't know the film myself, but I'd be interested to watch it if we can find an answer.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

You may be looking for the movie Wings of Fame 1990

A famous movie actor (Peter O'Toole) claims that he has written a book. As result, a real author, not a very well known writer, vengenfully kills him but then dies as a result of an accident. Next, they both find themselves in after-life, where souls of all famous people are gathered.

I believe they are taken by boat to the island in the middle of a lake. There are residents at a hotel including famous people such as Albert Einstein and Ernest Hemingway.
Possible Spoiler regarding celebrities staying at the nice hotel:

The reason for the celebrities staying at the nice hotel relates to public interest. For instance if they are no longer popular they start to be given smaller rooms. At some point they will inevitably be chucked out the nicer establishment.

